# Parsing 1:2:10 string into 3 variables

Tags: bash, shell, sh

In bash shell, what is the best way to parse input string 1:2:10 to set A=1, B=2, C=10 ?  Automatically set A, B, C to the 3 numbers separated by ':'.

In addition, if the input only has 1:10, set A=1, C=10, and then B = some default value.

Yes, I'm trying to simulate the format used in Matlab.  1:2:10 is expanded to 1, 3, 5, 7, 9 and 1:10 is expanded to 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10.  I'm thinking if I can get A, B, and C set right, it's easy to do this behavior.

Thanks!!

Comment: Once you parse out the numbers, `seq 1 2 10` and `seq 1 10` have your desired expansion behavior.

Comment: Bash has brace expansion: `echo {1..10..2}`, `echo {1..10}` - see the [manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Brace-Expansion).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this all in one simple bash function:

```
s()( IFS=:; seq $1; )
```

That creates a local environment (which is why the definition has parentheses instead of braces) inside which `IFS` is modified to split on colon. Because of the local `IFS`, `$1` is word-split with colons. Since `seq` expects two or three arguments precisely in the order you specify, the result is pretty well as you expect:

```
$ s 1:2:10
1
3
5
7
9
$ s 2:4
2
3
4
```

Variable substitutions will work, since they are done before `s` is invoked:

```
$ from=1 to=6 by=2
$ s $from:$by:$to
1
3
5
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$ IFS=: read a b c <<< '1:2:10'
$ echo $a
1
$ echo $b
2
$ echo $c
10
$ seq "$a" "$b" "$c"
1
3
5
7
9
$ IFS=: read a b c <<< '1:10'
$ echo $c

$ [ "$c" ] || seq "$a" "$b"
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
```

Comment: Thanks Ignacio!!  is this IFS a system variable?  should I restore it after my .sh ?

Comment: Placing it before the command as shown above will only set it for the invocation of that single command.